# How to execute a spring batch job by clicking on a button in a jsp page?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-batch

I'm a newbie in spring batch and spring Mvc, and I want that a batch job (which extracts data from a database and writes it in another database) is executed from a jsp page by clicking on a button (or a link if it's possible) I'm using spring Mvc. This is my job configuration:

```
    <bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
</bean>



<bean id="itemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql"
        value="select id,name,qual from users" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="tn.com.spring.UserRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="oracleitemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[        
            insert into users2(id,name,qual) 
        values (:id,:name,:qual)
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>


<batch:job id="Job" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="oracleitemWriter"
                commit-interval=" 10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>

</batch:job>


<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script
        location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

and this is my job controller (I found it in the net but still not working!)

```
@Component
@Controller()
public class JobController {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("JobLauncher")
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("Job")
private Job job;

@RequestMapping(value = "/job")
public void job() {
try {
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);

}
} 

}
```

and here is the button

```
<form action=" <%=application.getContextPath()%>/job" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="execute My job" />
</form>
```

Could you please help me ? Whats's missing in my configuration? 
I'm confused !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error?  What is happening or not happening? Do you have a stack trace?  In order to help you, we need to know what's happening.

Comment: Hi @Michael, the problem is there is no error ! 
I don't know if there is a missing configuration, 
when I click on the button the job is not executed ..

Comment: Ok...is the controller called?

Comment: I've made some changes in the jsp page by creating  a javascript method,
when I click on the button the controller is called and the job is launched... Thanks @Michael for your time :)

Comment: @pietà i know its too late to ask you think but can you share what you added to the code that worked for you? I need to do exactly the same thing!

Comment: @IbrahimNadir  see my answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution for this problem, I have made this  javascript code which will invoke the execution of the job :

```
    $(function() {

    $('#JobBtn').click(function() {
        $.get('${batchJobUrl}');
    });
});
```

and in the jsp page you need to specify the Id of the button  writen in the javascript code:

```
<input type="button" value="execute job " id='JobBtn' class="btn" />
```

I Hope it will help someOne..